# How to Override Product Shipping Price in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

I found this solution, but error is coming which is undefined `$method`.

The code which I found was this:

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier\Tablerate" />
</config>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier\Tablerate.php

```
 <?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

class Tablerate extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate
{
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        //Do your logic before this line and return your custom price.
        $shippingPrice = 50;
        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
class Tablerate extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate
{
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        $result = parent::collectRates($request);
        //Do your logic before this line and return your custom price.
        $shippingPrice = 50;
        foreach ($result->getAllRates() as $method) {
            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

but anyway I'll recommend you to overwrite a price of tablerate shipping method using a `.csv` file or if it is not suitable for your conditions you can write just a plugin. Rewrite class completely is not a good idea.

---

#### Update:

Here is a plugin example.

Add a sequence to load a module after the original one:

> app/code/Vendor/TableRatesPrice/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_TableRatesPrice" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_OfflineShipping"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Define a plugin:

> app/code/Vendor/TableRatesPrice/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Plugins -->
    <!-- Fixes magento's core bug -->
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate">
        <plugin name="change_table_rate_price"
                type="Vendor\TableRatesPrice\Plugin\ChangeRatesPrice"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Replace a price inside the plugin:

> app/code/Vendor/TableRatesPrice/Plugin/ChangeRatesPrice.php

```
namespace Vendor\TableRatesPrice\Plugin;

use Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result as RateResult;

/**
 * Class ChangeRatesPrice
 */
class ChangeRatesPrice
{
    public function afterCollectRates(Tablerate $subject, RateResult $result, RateRequest $request)
    {
        //Do your logic before this line and return your custom price.
        $shippingPrice = 50;
        foreach ($result->getAllRates() as $method) {
            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

If you want to use this example as a complete module do not forget to add a `registration.php` and `composer.json` files:

> app/code/Vendor/TableRatesPrice/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_TableRatesPrice',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/TableRatesPrice/composer.json

```
{
  "name": "vendor/module-table-rates-price",
  "description": "N/A",
  "require": {
    "magento/module-offline-shipping": ">=100.1.0 < 101"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\TableRatesPrice\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Here is [complete example on GitHub](https://github.com/SiarheyUchukhlebau/TableRatesPrice).

Comment: Sir can you please describe a little more and if possible can you tell me which  is the proper to override shipping charges?

Comment: i have to put delivery charges depending upon the quantity of product being ordered?

Comment: if weight of product is 1kg then delivery charge should 4$ if it is 3kg then delivery charge should be 5$?..............Help required!

Comment: @AnkurAnand you can get more info about how to setup the table rates shipping method here https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

Comment: ok.....How can i do that with a plug in because my conditions are complicated so i think it will be better if i do programmaticaly  ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand, do want to do it with plugin ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand I've update my answer